# Using a shared varibale to select from a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, theano

I'm trying to select multiple elements from a matrix using a changing vector, which is sent to my Theano function at each iteration. But when I try running the code I get the following error for the last line (selecting from W)

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The declaration is:

```
x = T.vector('x', dtype='int32')
y = T.vector('y', dtype='int32')

net = net(rng=rng, x=x, n_in=dim*5, n_out=2, n_hidden=100, y=y, n_tokens=len(txt), dim=dim)
```

and then I use my input (x) as follows:

```
W = numpy.asarray(
    rng.uniform(low=0., high=1., size=(n_tokens, dim)),
    dtype=theano.config.floatX
)
self.W = theano.shared(value=W, name='W', borrow=True)

self.output = W[x, ]
```

The intention is that at run time x will be a simple vector of indices of the form

```
x = [0, 1, 5, 98....]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: That type of `ValueError` typically arises when something is a list that shouldn't be, or there is a list of lists of different lengths interpreted as an array. I can't identify where this is happening, but please make sure you are posting *working code* for us: `W[x, ]` looks very much like R notation; in python `x, == (x,)` is a tuple containing `x` and although this may work, it is a very implicit way of going about things ...

Answer (score 1):

The matrix W is of numpy ndarray type, so it does not know how to deal with Theano tensors such as x. If you want to index this numpy array, use a numpy index array instead of a Theano tensor. If you want to index the Theano tensor self.W, you will have to wait for the next release of Theano, or update to the development version: the [theano manual](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing) says that:

> Like NumPy, Theano distinguishes between basic and advanced indexing. Theano fully supports basic indexing (see NumPy’s indexing).
>
> Integer advanced indexing will be supported in 0.6rc4 (or the development version). We do not support boolean masks, as Theano does not have a boolean type (we use int8 for the output of logic operators).

Comment: Thank you. So to index self.W I could either update Theano or loop through all of my indices adding them to self.output each at a time. Do you know anything about dev version? is it stable enough?

Comment: I'm not using the development version myself, so I don't know. You could just try it out and revert back if you run into problems. Or you can ask on the theano mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/theano-users

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `inc_subtensor` or `set_subtensor` for this type of behavior, instead of slicing. See http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.set_subtensor for more details.